# Google Analytics Country has more Page Views than Sessions

Tags: google-analytics

I have a custom report set in Google Analytics and when I view the metrics via Country, it's telling me the lowest page views didn't have any sessions but a small number of page views. I'm trying to get my head around sessions are really entrances, but I can't see how this applies when viewing by country? The custom report only tracks users who are logged in to my site and not the register/sign in page.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that entrances don't necessarily need to be sessions if your first hit isn't a pageview hit but rather something else like an event hit. In this case you would have incremented your sessions, but not the entrances.

Answer (score 1):

The official Analytics documentation states ["Sessions is incremented on, and associated with, the first hit of the session."](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en)

Since you said you only track users who are logged in to your site, I imagine that is due to users who come to your site and still have to log in.
The session metric is incremented when they hit your site. I guess after loging into their accounts they are redirected to a new page (which is when your custom reports starts to count), where the session is not counted again.

Example:

1. User lands on the login page of your domain (session = 1)
2. Users logs in and gets redirected (session = 0)
3. User continues to navigate multiple pages (session = 0)

Only steps 2. and 3. are covered by your custom report, hence you have 0 sessions. On the other hand, users coming to your site that are still logged in will increment the session metric in your report.

This is what I can think of without any given other information. Adding the Unique Pageviews metric might help to narrow down your problem.